# How to avoid 'Adding a Configuration as a dependency is a confusing behavior which isn't recommended' in Gradle

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I have two projects. One has a producer configuration:

```kotlin
// gen/build.gradle.kts

...

val outDir = layout.projectDirectory.dir("output")

val run = tasks.named<JavaExec>("run") {
    args = listOf(outDir.asFile.absolutePath)
}

configurations.create("generated") {
    isCanBeResolved = false
    isCanBeConsumed = true
}

artifacts {
    add("generated", outDir) {
        builtBy(run)
    }
}
```

The root project then has a consumer configuration which is used in the application:

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts

...

val generated by configurations.creating<Configuration> {
    isCanBeResolved = true
    isCanBeConsumed = false
}

dependencies {
    generated(project(mapOf(
        "path" to ":gen",
        "configuration" to "generated",
    )))

    api(generated)
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        kotlin {
            srcDir(generated.files)
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm currently using `dependencies` to declare that the `:generated` configuration depends on the `:gen:generated` configuration. This is how the docs [currently suggest declaring this dependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/cross_project_publications.html#sec:simple-sharing-artifacts-between-projects).

However, it triggers a deprecation warning: `Adding a Configuration as a dependency is a confusing behavior which isn't recommended. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. If you're interested in inheriting the dependencies from the Configuration you are adding, you should use Configuration#extendsFrom instead. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration:extendsFrom(org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration[]) for more details.`

So I try using `extendsFrom` instead:

```kotlin
// In build.gradle.kts

val generated by configurations.creating<Configuration> {
    isCanBeResolved = true
    isCanBeConsumed = false

    extendsFrom(project(":gen").configurations.getByName("generated"))
}

dependencies {
    api(generated)
}
```

And get: `Configuration with name 'generated' not found.`

Based on [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54833783/12916297), I suspect this could be caused by the `gen` project's configuration phase not having happened yet. So I try:

```kotlin
// In build.gradle.kts

val generated by configurations.creating<Configuration> {
    isCanBeResolved = true
    isCanBeConsumed = false

    project(":gen").afterEvaluate {
        extendsFrom(project(":gen").configurations.getByName("generated"))
    }
}
```

But now it seems to be declaring the inheritance too late:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':gen'.
> Cannot change dependencies of dependency configuration ':generated' after it has been resolved.
```

What am I supposed to do to avoid this deprecation warning?

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the fun world of [sharing outputs between Gradle subprojects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/cross_project_publications.html)!

There's a few different ways of solving this problem.

Since you're working with a JVM project you might want to configure a [feature variant](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/feature_variants.html). Gradle will then create a new source set, and you can generate your files into this.

But, if you're not using a JVM project, then things get a little bit more complicated. I'll explain the simplest and most straight forward way. Please stop laughing, that wasn't a joke. Yes I know, it's still complicated. Trust me, it's worth it.

What we'll end up with is a robust way to share files between projects in a way that's cacheable (being compatible with both [Build Cache](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html) and [Configuration Cache](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/configuration_cache.html)), flexible, re-usable, and gain a good understanding of how Gradle works.

#### Tasks

Here's the summary of what needs to be done:

- Create a [buildSrc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources) convention plugin
- Set up some configurations* for [*declaring*, *providing* and *consuming*](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sec:resolvable-consumable-configs) files
- Define a custom [variant attribute](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/variant_attributes.html) as a marker, to differentiate our configurations from others
- Put the files produced by a task into the *outgoing* configuration
- Resolve the files from other subprojects using the *incoming* configuration

**Yes, the name [configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management_terminology.html#sub:terminology_configuration) is confusing. In this context 'configuration' should be better renamed as 'DependencyContainer' - they're just a collection of files that might be *outgoing* or *incoming* to a subproject, along with some metadata to describe the contents.*

#### Creating a buildSrc convention plugin

We need to be able to set-up our providing and consuming code in both the providing and consuming subprojects. While technically we could copy-paste it, that kind sucks and far too finickity. The best way to share config in Gradle is with a convention plugin.

I've gone over setting up convention plugins in another answer ([Configure Kotlin extension for Gradle subprojects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71883613/configure-kotlin-extension-for-gradle-subprojects/71892685#71892685)), so I'll just summarise the steps here.

1. Create the build config for buildSrc.

   Since buildSrc is effectively a standalone project, it's best to create a `settings.gradle.kts` file. I like using a [centralised repositories declaration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:centralized-repository-declaration).

   ```kotlin
   // buildSrc/settings.gradle.kts

   rootProject.name = "buildSrc"

   pluginManagement {
     repositories {
       mavenCentral()
       gradlePluginPortal()
     }
   }

   @Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")
   dependencyResolutionManagement {

     repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)

     repositories {
       mavenCentral()
       gradlePluginPortal()
     }
   }
   ```

   The `build.gradle.kts` just needs the [Kotlin DSL plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#sec:kotlin-dsl_plugin). This will make writing our convention plugin much more easy as [precompiled script plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:precompiled_plugins)

   ```kotlin
   // buildSrc/build.gradle.kts

   plugins {
     `kotlin-dsl`
   }
   ```
2. Create our convention plugin. The name of the file (everything before `.gradle.kts`), and the [`package`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package) (if one is defined) will be the plugin ID

   ```kotlin
   // buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/generated-files-sharing.gradle.kts

   logger.lifecycle("I don't do anything yet...")
   ```

Done! You can test it by applying this do-nothing plugin to your subprojects.

```kotlin
// my-generator/build.gradle.kts

plugins {
  id("generated-files-sharing")
}
```

```kotlin
// my-consumer/build.gradle.kts

plugins {
  id("generated-files-sharing")
}
```

When you run a task (e.g. `./gradlew help`), you should see the message `I don't do anything yet...` logged to the console.

#### Creating configurations for providing and consuming files

The next step is creating some configurations, which are the [shipping containers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shipping_container) of Gradle's dependencies world.

We're going to make three configurations

- One for *declaring* dependencies (e.g. `dependencies { generatedFiles(project(":my-generator")) }`),
- one for *incoming* files,
- and another for *outgoing* files.

Take note of `isCanBeConsumed` and `isCanBeResolved`*. In Gradle terminology, the incoming one will be *resolved* by a subproject, and the outgoing one will be *consumed* by other subprojects. [It's important to use the right combination](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sec:resolvable-consumable-configs).

**Again, we have some confusing names. The terms 'consumed' and 'resolved' aren't very clear, they both seem like synonyms to me. They would be better renamed to indicate that `consumed=true && resolved=false` means `OUTGOING`, and `consumed=false && resolved=true` means `INCOMING`*

```kotlin
// buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/generated-files-sharing.gradle.kts

// create the Configuration that will contain declared dependencies
val generatedFiles by configurations.creating {
   description = "Declare dependencies on generated files from other subprojects"

   // this Configuration won't resolve or share files...
   isCanBeResolved = false
   isCanBeConsumed = false
   // it will only be used to declare dependencies
   isCanBeDeclared = true
}

// create the incoming Configuration that will resolve the files declared as dependencies
val generatedFilesResolver: Configuration by configurations.creating {
   description = "Resolves generated files from other subprojects"

   // the dependencies in this Configuration will be resolved by this subproject...
   isCanBeResolved = true
   // and so they won't be consumed by other subprojects
   isCanBeConsumed = false
   isCanBeDeclared = false

   extendsFrom(generatedFiles)
}

// create the outgoing Configuration that will share generated files
val generatedFilesProvider: Configuration by configurations.creating {
   description = "Provides generated files to other subprojects"

   // the dependencies in this configuration won't be resolved by this subproject...
   isCanBeResolved = false
   // but they will be consumed by other subprojects
   isCanBeConsumed = true
   isCanBeDeclared = false
}
```

*(Note that `isCanBeDeclared` requires Gradle 8.2. If you're on lower versions, you can just not use it, and only set the consumed/declared flags. The result will be the same.)*

What's cool about this step is that if you now jump to your subproject you can use these configurations as if they were built into Gradle (after an [IDE sync](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tutorials/working-with-gradle/syncing-and-reloading/), if necessary).

```kotlin
// my-consumer/build.gradle.kts

plugins {
  id("generated-files-sharing")
}

dependencies {
  generatedFiles(project(":my-generator"))
}
```

Gradle has generated a [type-safe accessor](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#type-safe-accessors) for the `generatedFiles` configuration.

However, we're not done. We haven't put any files into the outgoing configuration, so of course the consuming project isn't going to be able to resolve any files. But before we do that, we need to add that metadata I mentioned.

#### Differentiate our configurations with variant attributes

It's quite likely that the subproject that provides the generated files also has other configurations with completely different file types. But we don't want to fill up the `generatedFiles` configuration with lots of files, we *only* want generated files produced by our generate task.

That's where [variant attributes](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management_terminology.html#sub:terminology_attribute) come in. If configurations were shipping containers, then the variant attributes are the shipping labels on the outside that describe where the contents should be sent.

At a basic level, variant attributes are just key-value strings, except the keys should be [registered with Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/variant_attributes.html#creating_attributes_in_a_build_script_or_plugin). We can skip that registration though if we use a built-in [standard attribute](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/variant_attributes.html#sec:standard_attributes). The [Usage](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/attributes/Usage.html) attribute is a good pick. It's pretty commonly used, so long as we pick a distinctive value Gradle is going to be able to differentiate between two configurations by comparing the values.

```kotlin
// buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/generated-files-sharing.gradle.kts

// create a custom Usage attribute value, with a distinctive value
val generatedFilesUsageAttribute: Usage =
  objects.named<Usage>("my.library.generated-files")

val generatedFiles by configurations.creating {
   description = "Declare dependencies on generated files from other subprojects"

   isCanBeResolved = false
   isCanBeConsumed = false
   isCanBeDeclared = true
   
   // no attributes in declarable Configurations
}

val generatedFilesResolver by configurations.creating {
   description = "Resolves generated files from other subprojects"

   isCanBeResolved = true
   isCanBeConsumed = false
   isCanBeDeclared = false
   
   extendsFrom(generatedFiles)

   // add the attribute to the incoming configuration
   attributes {
      attribute(Usage.USAGE_ATTRIBUTE, generatedFilesUsageAttribute)
   }
}

val generatedFilesProvider by configurations.creating {
  description = "Provides generated files to other subprojects"

  isCanBeResolved = false
  isCanBeConsumed = true
  isCanBeDeclared = false

  // also add the attribute to the outgoing configuration
  attributes {
    attribute(Usage.USAGE_ATTRIBUTE, generatedFilesUsageAttribute)
  }
}
```

What's important is that the *same* attribute key and value are added to both configurations. Now, Gradle can happily match both the incoming and outgoing configurations!

Now all the parts are in place. We're almost done! It's time to start pushing files into the configuration, and pulling files out.

#### Putting files into the *outgoing* configuration

In the subproject that produces the generated files, let's say we have some task that produces some files. I'll use a [Sync task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:sync_task) as a stand-in for the actual generator task.

```kotlin
// my-generator/build.gradle.kts

plugins {
  id("generated-files-sharing")
}

val myGeneratorTask by tasks.registering(Sync::class) {
  from(resources.text.fromString("hello, world!"))
  into(temporaryDir)
}
```

Note that the output directory doesn't really matter, because thanks to Gradle's Provider API, a [task can be converted into a file-provider](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html#working_with_task_dependencies_in_lazy_properties).

```kotlin
// my-generator/build.gradle.kts

configurations.generatedFilesProvider.configure { 
  outgoing { 
    artifact(myGeneratorTask.map { it.temporaryDir })
  }
}
```

What's nice about this is that now Gradle will *only* configure and run the `myGeneratorTask` task if it requested. When this kind of [configuration avoidance](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html) is regularly used, then it can really help speed up Gradle builds.

#### Resolving the incoming configuration

We're at the last step!

In the consuming project we can add a dependency on the providing project using the regular `dependencies {}` block.

```kotlin
// my-consumer/build.gradle.kts

plugins {
  id("generated-files-sharing")
}

dependencies {
  generatedFiles(project(":my-generator"))
}
```

And now we can get the *incoming* files from the incoming (resolvable) configuration:

```kotlin
// my-consumer/build.gradle.kts

val myConsumerTask by tasks.registering(Sync::class) {
  from(configurations.generatedFilesResolver)
  into(temporaryDir)
}
```

Now if you run `./gradlew myConsumerTask` you'll notice that, even though you haven't explicitly set any [task dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:adding_dependencies_to_tasks), Gradle will automatically run `myGeneratorTask`.

And if you check the contents of `myConsumerTask`'s temporary directory (`./my-consumer/build/tmp/myConsumerTask/`), you'll see the generated file.

If you re-run the same command, then you should see that Gradle will avoid running the tasks because they are [UP-TO-DATE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15137271/4161471).

You can also enable [Gradle Build Cache](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html) (`./gradlew myConsumerTask --build-cache`) and even if you delete generated files (remove  the `./my-generator/build/` directory) you should see that both `myGeneratorTask` and `myConsumerTask` are [loaded FROM-CACHE](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html#sec:task_output_caching)

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed answer. I'm still a bit stuck adapting it for my project, though; how can I use the generated files from the incoming configuration as part of the source set for the application?
I've tried:
`sourceSets { main { kotlin { srcDir(configurations.generatedFiles.map { it.incoming.artifacts.artifactFiles.singleFile }) } } }`
But this causes a stack overflow (recursively trying to interpret it as a file?)! However, if I use `get` instead of `map`, it doesn't generate in time and I get unknown identifier errors

Comment: I suspect that it's not possible to use a configuration as a source set dir, even if it's converted to be a `Provider<File>`. Instead, try using the `myConsumerTask` Sync task I defined to consume the configuration files, and then convert the task to a file provider, and use it as a SourceSet srcDir. The task will also work with multiple incoming files.

Comment: Is there a way to define a consumer task for that purpose without unnecessarily copying the files?

Comment: Actually I'm struggling even to get it to work with the Sync task. While I really appreciate your answer which has helped me get past the "basic" configuration sharing and into using variant attributes and a plugin, what I really need to know as in my question is how to use a configuration as a source set dir – other than with the deprecated setup I described.
I don't understand why I could just use `generated.files` before, but with this new setup the `files` property no longer exists on the configuration.

Comment: @aSemy this is one of the most useful answers I've ever seen on StackOverflow and I have been coding for over 10 years. Awesome write up!