# How to inherit dependencies scope from different Gradle sub-projects?

Tags: gradle, gradle-dependencies, gradle-submodule

Consider the following simple build (`settings.gradle.kts`):

```kotlin
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

include("main-module")
include("specific-test-module")
```

The main module is as simple as:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("java")
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.9")
}
```

My goal is to inherit `implementation` dependencies from `main-module` in `testImplementation` scope in `specific-tests-module`. The test module is so specific, that I have created a separate Gradle sub-project for it. Now I am trying to achieve my goal with `extendsFrom` on configuration, but the problem is that `extendsFrom` stops working as soon as I try to use it outside of a single Gradle sub-project.

While adding a new scope in `main-module/build.gradle.kts` works as expected:

```kotlin
configurations.create("someNewScope") {
    extendsFrom(configurations.implementation.get()) // <--- 'someNewScope' will inherit 'slf4j-api'
}
```

an attempt to inherit scope in another sub-project does not make any effect:

```kotlin
configurations.create("someScope") {
    extendsFrom(project(":main-module").configurations.implementation.get())
}
```

Seems like an attempt to read configuration of another sub-project happens too early, when dependencies of another sub-project are not yet configured. How can I make scopes inheritance to work between different Gradle's sub-projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic and the only recommended approach to share something between Gradle projects is to use "Variants". Here is the corresponding documentation section: [Producing and Consuming Variants of Libraries > Sharing outputs between projects](https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/userguide/cross_project_publications.html).

It explicitly says:

> Don’t reference other project tasks directly

and provides the following anti-pattern example:

```kotlin
dependencies {
   // this is unsafe!
   implementation project(":other").tasks.someOtherJar
}
```

Very similar to what I've tried to do initially and it was wrong.

In my case it was enough to follow the [Simple sharing of artifacts between projects](https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/userguide/cross_project_publications.html#sec:simple-sharing-artifacts-between-projects) section of the documentation and expose dependencies through "consumable" configurations like this:

```kotlin
val exportedCompileOnly by configurations.creating {
    isCanBeConsumed = true
    isCanBeResolved = false
    extendsFrom(configurations.compileOnly.get())
}

val exportedTestImplementation by configurations.creating {
    isCanBeConsumed = true
    isCanBeResolved = false
    extendsFrom(configurations.implementation.get())
}

val exportedTestRuntimeOnly by configurations.creating {
    isCanBeConsumed = true
    isCanBeResolved = false
    extendsFrom(configurations.runtimeOnly.get())
}
```

After that I was able to add dependency on a project and inherit its exposed configurations as follows:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    testImplementation(project(":main-module"))
    testImplementation(project(mapOf("path" to ":main-module", "configuration" to "exportedTestImplementation")))
    testCompileOnly(project(mapOf("path" to ":main-module", "configuration" to "exportedCompileOnly")))
    testRuntimeOnly(project(mapOf("path" to ":main-module", "configuration" to "exportedTestRuntimeOnly")))
}
```

---

The reason why it's necessary to create additional configuration which from the first sight just `extendsFrom` already existing configuration is because you need "consumable" configuration to make it visible to other projects.
Here "consumable" configuration is a *variant* of how other Gradle projects can consume the project when specifying it in `dependency {}` block.

In my solution I:

- implicitly used a default variant by declaring dependency as `testImplementation(project(":main-module"))` (to add dependency on `src/main` of `main-module`)
- and also added dependencies on different variants of `main-module` by explicitly specifying variant name, for example `testImplementation(project(mapOf("path" to ":main-module", "configuration" to "exportedTestImplementation")))` (to inherit dependencies of `:main-module` through "consumable" configuration)

---

Additional references:

- [Detailed explanation of sharing through variants from other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75957228/3581539)
- [Understanding Gradle #08 – Declaring Dependencies, Terminology: Configurations for declaring/resolving/consuming](https://youtu.be/igug9tbl4J4?t=609&si=BWHgVEqXaFjTpGm3)
- [Understanding Gradle #13 – Aggregating Custom Artifacts, How does variant selection work?](https://youtu.be/2gPJD0mAres?t=461&si=YuGVEM0rjxoAM6n_)